2024 Election: Community Interest Check
Coffee Stack Exchange is looking for a moderator to join the team. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, we’re posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual nomination period starts.
Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position.
NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.
